# How to save data received via push notification for an app in Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, ios, firebase, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging.

When I receive a push notification, I have two scenarios:

1. When the app is in the foreground (or running) I use following code to save data

```
  public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
        {
            var body = message.GetNotification().Body;
            var title = message.GetNotification().Title;
            string[] notificationMessage = { title, body };
            MessagingCenter.Send<object, string[]>(this, Constants.TOPIC, notificationMessage);
            Preferences.Set("title", message[0]);
            Preferences.Set("body", message[1]);
            SendNotification(title, body, message.Data);
        }
```

The above code is working fine data is getting saved in preferneces.

2. But when it is not running then when I receive notification it is not getting saved.
   Is there any way I can do this in Android and iOS in Xamarin Forms

> > > > > > UPDATED<<<<<<<

```
#FirebaseMessageService
 public class UWTFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
    {
        public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
        {
            var body = message.GetNotification().Body;
            var title = message.GetNotification().Title;
            string[] notificationMessage = { title, body };
            MessagingCenter.Send<object, string[]>(this, Constants.TOPIC, notificationMessage);
            SendNotification(title, body, message.Data);
        }

        void SendNotification(string messageTitle, string messageBody, IDictionary<string, string> data)
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            intent.PutExtra("title", messageTitle);
            intent.PutExtra("body", messageBody);
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
            foreach (var key in data.Keys)
            {
                intent.PutExtra(key, data[key]);
            }

            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this,
                                                          MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_ID,
                                                          intent,
                                                          PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

            var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, Constants.CHANNEL_ID)
                                      .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)
                                      .SetContentTitle(messageTitle)
                                      .SetContentText(messageBody)
                                      .SetAutoCancel(true)
                                      .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);
            notificationManager.Notify(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.Build());
        }
    }
```

## MainActivity

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            RequestPermissions(Permission, RequestId);
            HtmlLabelRenderer.Initialize();
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            GAService.GetGASInstance().InitializeNativeGAS(this);
            CreateNotificationChannel();
            FirebaseMessaging.Instance.SubscribeToTopic(Constants.TOPIC);
            LoadApplication(new App());
            if (Intent.Extras != null)
            {
                foreach (var key in Intent.Extras.KeySet())
                {
                    if (key == "title")
                    {
                        var value = Intent.Extras.GetString(key);
                        Preferences.Set("title", value);
                    }
                    else if (key == "body")
                    {
                        var value = Intent.Extras.GetString(key);
                        Preferences.Set("body", value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
       

        void CreateNotificationChannel()
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                // Notification channels are new in API 26 (and not a part of the
                // support library). There is no need to create a notification
                // channel on older versions of Android.
                return;
            }

            var channel = new NotificationChannel(Constants.CHANNEL_ID,
                                                  Constants.CHANNEL_NAME,
                                                  NotificationImportance.Default)
            {

                Description = Constants.CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION
            };

            var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.NotificationService);
            notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        //for foreground and backgrounded state
        protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
        {

            if (intent != null)
            {
                var title = intent.GetStringExtra("title");
                var body = intent.GetStringExtra("body");

                Preferences.Set("title", title);
                Preferences.Set("body", body);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi can you share your notifcation payload structre?

Comment: @Anand I have used this tutorial .https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I ran this similar issue few days ago.According to firebase documentation [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=windows) there are two types of notifications can be created.

1. Notification messages
2. Data messages

If we are sending notification messages, and our app is closed the `OnMessageReceived` will never called.

If we are sending Data messages, then when our app in either forground or background or closed the `OnMessageReceived` will call.

So, you can manage the notification messages if your app is closed, using the intents.

**In your Firebase Messeging service**

```
public static string title = "";
public static string body = "";

 public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
            base.OnMessageReceived(message);
            var body = message.GetNotification().Body;
            var title = message.GetNotification().Title;
            string[] notificationMessage = { title, body };
            MessagingCenter.Send<object, string[]>(this, Constants.TOPIC, notificationMessage);  
            SendNotification(title, body, message.Data);
     }  


      private void SendNotification(string messageBody, IDictionary<string, string> data)
     {

        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.PutExtra("title", title);
        intent.PutExtra("body", body);

        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
        foreach (var key in data.Keys)
        {
            intent.PutExtra(key, data[key]);
        }
        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_ID, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);
        var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MainActivity.CHANNEL_ID).SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_launcher).SetContentTitle("your notification").SetContentText(messageBody).SetAutoCancel(true).SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this); notificationManager.Notify(MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.Build());
  }
```

**In your Main Activity**

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

           LoadApplication(new App());

          //  For killed app state
             if (Intent.Extras != null)
             {
                foreach (var key in Intent.Extras.KeySet())
                {
                    if (key != null)
                    {
                        if(key== "title")
                        {
                            var value = Intent.Extras.GetString(key);
                            Preferences.Set("title", value);                                                    
                        }      
                       else if(key== "body")            
                       {
                            var value = Intent.Extras.GetString(key);
                            Preferences.Set("body", value); 
                       }

                }
            }   

        }
    }
    //after oncreate
    //for foreground and backgrounded state
    protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
        {

            if (intent != null)
            {
                var title = intent.GetStringExtra("title");
                var body = intent.GetStringExtra("body");

              Preferences.Set("title", title);   
              Preferences.Set("body", body); 
            }

        }
```

Comment: Great, Thank you for the help

Comment: I will also need help in iOS. I am using Firebase.CloudMessaging in iOS.
The reason behind saving it into preferences is basically I need to display it on the app screen.

Comment: Can you able to receive and store data for forground notifications is ios?

Comment: No, I am not sure which method I will use. Ok, I will ask a separate question for that.
Let me test this one first on Android as I just noticed it is getting in preferences when the app is closed

Comment: data not getting saved in preferences. I am not sure why

Comment: in android  or ios?

Comment: in android. just wanted to make sure the variable you created for title and body, are we need to use the same variable in OnMessageReceived?

Comment: Its your choice.. The idea is the intent and accessing it from mainactvity

Comment: Its the way I done. You can get the title and body from notifcation like you done. Just pass that parameters as intent. The keys for intent must be same in mainactivty

Comment: I have updated code the question. Please check again

Comment: Hi, so what is the iisue now? did the data not saving in both foreground and closed state?

Comment: So I am using Firebase Console to trigger a message when app state is closed, (or minimized )  , data not getting saved.  probably onMessageReceived not getting called

Comment: Ok. So you should send the notification as data message.when you implement this on your backend.

Comment: Alright, so it can not be done from the firebase console?

Comment: From console we can send notifcation message with some additional parameter. You can find Additional options (optional). option in console. But in order to send data messages we can only done it from backend.

Comment: It will trigger OnMessage recieved in any of your app state

Comment: Thank you. actually the requirement is not to develop a backend. so I just wanted to make sure is it feasible or not.

Comment: Oh okey bro...For ios configuration you can refer https://www.appcoda.com/firebase-push-notifications/          https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/159477/xamarin-forms-push-notification-is-not-receiving-to-ios-device#latest  https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/161408/xamarin-forms-how-to-handle-the-notification-click-in-ios#latest